# .htaccess hide subdirectory url after redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, url-masking

I'm redirecting a website to a subdirectory I created. The subdirectory contains an installation of WordPress and now I want to mask the subdirectory url from the website.

Now it's something like http://mywebsite.com/apt/

I want to remove the /apt/ from the URL.

I tried everything today, searched on Google, tried to write various things on the htaccess I found here but nothing works.

On the htaccess on the main directory of the site, I use this code to redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com/\apt" [R=301,L]
```

And on the one in the /apt/ folder I have

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apt/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /apt/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Could someone suggest me how can I hide the /apt/ extension from the URL?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with this:
remove the redirect part then use this insead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /apt/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^apt/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule !^apt/ apt%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

then use the same code for the main website.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A detailed explanation of each line would transform this mediocre answer into something excellent.

Answer (score 1):

*Create a .htaccess file in root folder, and put this content inside (just change `example.com` and `my_subdir`):*

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
      RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove /apt from url why do you redirect "/" to "/apt"?
Try this:

```
RewriteRule !^apt/ /apt%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

instead of

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com/\apt" [R=301,L]
```

With this rewrite you should see your application in /apt folder under url www.mywebsite.com

Comment: I updated my answer, because I found some bug, try this new version: RewriteRule !^apt/ /apt%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]